# Depth of the \times symbol

Tags: symbols, vertical-alignment

I just noticed an annoying discrepancy involving the `\times` symbol's depth.  Read the below code and then try to guess what it should look like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\fbox{$A$} \fbox{$B$}

\fbox{$A \times A$} \fbox{$B$} \hrule
\end{document}
```

If you typeset this, you will see that the top line is perfectly level, while the `\hrule` is noticeably below the second *B* and the box around `$A \times A$` is noticeably deep.  Yet, I would consider both `$A$` and `$A \times A$` to be text-height and zero-depth expressions.  Now replace `\times` by `\smash\times` and you will see the problem go away; unfortunately, you will also see the spacing break since `\smash` ruins the math-operatorness of `\times`.

Am I right?  `\times` has a nearly invisible depth and this distorts the center of expressions, otherwise having no depth, in which it is written.  How should I work around this?

Comment: Note that this effect depends on the math typeface you use. A quick check of the following Type1 typefaces gives the following results -- Problematic `\times`: Computer Modern, AMS Fonts (CM), Arev Math, CM Bright, Euler VM, Math Design, Pazo (mathpazo). No problem: Adobe Minion Pro, Fourier, JAM Times (Belleek), Kepler Project, MT Pro2 (commercial), txfonts.

Comment: @Geoffrey Jones: Well, that's a valuable list.  Thanks!  Note: other operators may have this problem too.  `\otimes` has a *visible* depth, for example (in CM).  I haven't done any sort of testing, though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can `\smash` the `\times`, being careful to add a `\mathbin` too keep the spacing right:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\fbox{$A$} \fbox{$B$}

\fbox{$A \times A$} \fbox{$B$} \hrule

\fbox{$A \mathbin{\smash\times} A$} \fbox{$B$} \hrule
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Philippe gave you a good answer how to solve your problem. I'd like to explain why I think that the depth of `\times` is a feature and not a bug. As you observed, `\otimes` has a visible depth. Also `+`, `\oplus` and friends have a visible depth. Now the feature of the CM fonts is that all these symbols, including `\times` and even `-`(!!!) have the *same* depth. This can be very useful if, e.g., you have both `A\times B` and `A\otimes B`; it wouldn't look nice if there the spacing is different. This won't happen often, but think of `A+B` and `A-B`!

Comment: It is most definitely a feature. Knuth talks about it in a Q&A session transcripted in http://www.ntg.nl/maps/16/15.pdf#page=9 (it's the question by Johannes in the right column of page 9 of the PDF; it can also be found in Knuth's Digital Typography book, page 645).

Comment: This is an important point, I think.  In fact, it suggests that my problem is a bug on my side rather than TeX's (or, in this case, tikz's), since if this visible depth actually causes misalignment it's probably because I have failed to align the symbols along their baselines.  I think I'll go back and fix that now.