# LaTeX align/distribute objects à la InDesign?

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, boxes, adjustbox

I'm trying to replicate, in `LaTeX`, `InDesign`'s align and distribute tools. This is a snapshot of `ID`'s toolbar:

[image: indesign toolbar]

Say I want first to align vertically two objects (texts, graphics, boxes,...), and then align them horizontally, so that they become superimposed and completely centred. 
So, if the first object were `[  ]` and the second `x`, the first step would give me `[  ]x` and the second `[x]`.

Of course, I can do this with the `centre` environment and a negative `hspace` command and a bit of math.

What I would like to get is a more or less generalized (set of) command(s).

I believe this might be easily accomplished in `Tikz`, but I don't know how to. Or perhaps with the `adjustbox` package. Although this question is obviously wide, I wonder if someone has already inquired into this issue and can give me some ideas on it.

---

OK. As requested, this is more or less what I would like to systematise:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx, xcolor, calc}

\newcommand*{\FirstObject}{\colorbox{black!20}{\quad}}
\newcommand*{\SecondObject}{x}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\parindent=0pt

\section{First Step}
\newlength{\wone}
  \setlength{\wone}{\widthof{\FirstObject{}}}
\newlength{\wtwo}
  \setlength{\wtwo}{\widthof{\SecondObject{}}}
\newlength{\wthree}
  \setlength{\wthree}{\wone + \wtwo}

\FirstObject{}\hspace*{-.5\wthree}\SecondObject{}


\section{Second Step}
\newlength{\hone}
  \setlength{\hone}{\heightof{\FirstObject{}}}
\newlength{\htwo}
  \setlength{\htwo}{\heightof{\SecondObject{}}}
\newlength{\hthree}
  \setlength{\hthree}{\hone + \htwo}

\FirstObject{}\hspace*{-.5\wthree}%
\raisebox{-.25\hthree}{\SecondObject{}}  % Don't know why .5 won't work here...

\end{document}
```

[image: myexample]

Comment: This definitely needs a explanatory drawing/image.

Comment: You probably want `\ooalign`; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22375/4427)

Comment: @egreg Just tried it. Although it takes care of horizontal alignment (my first step), it doesn't give me vertical alignment (my second step). Furthermore, I would have to calculate beforehand which is the widest object.

Comment: You don't need to compute any width with `\ooalign`. You're not taking into account that `\colorbox` descends below the baseline. Perhaps a better example is needed.

Comment: Yes, I didn't know that about `\colorbox`. That's why I want a more general solution that doesn't require me to know that, i.e., that works for any two (or more) objects, irrespective of their characteristics.

Comment: So you want them vertically centered? Or what? And what's the placement with respect to the baseline?

Comment: Yes, I want---in the example at hand---to have the two objects fully centred, both horizontally and vertically.

Comment: You can determine the center of the box that contains a character but there is no way to determine the "center" of an arbitrary character. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61357/14500.

Comment: @PaulGaborit So, using boxes, is there a way to do what I want with `Tikz`?

Comment: @NVaughan Using boxes, the answer below is a way... You can also use TikZ.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might like the [`xcoffins`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcoffins) package which has very handy ways to join different kinds of boxes (so-called coffins) with another or attach one to another. It is part of the [`l3experimental`](http://ctan.org/pkg/l3experimental) bundle which means syntax changes are still possible.

There already are [some questions and answers on this site that deal with `xcoffins`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=xcoffins), here's another small example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcoffins}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\NewCoffin\FirstObject
\NewCoffin\SecondObject

\SetHorizontalCoffin\FirstObject{\colorbox{black!20}{\quad}}
\SetHorizontalCoffin\SecondObject{x}

\begin{document}

\TypesetCoffin\FirstObject

\TypesetCoffin\SecondObject

% join both coffins at their horizontal and vertical centers:
\JoinCoffins
  \FirstObject[hc,vc]%
  \SecondObject[hc,vc]%

% \FirstObject now holds the joined coffins:
\TypesetCoffin\FirstObject

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `\JoinCoffins` command does exactly what I wanted. Thanks.