# How to mark a point at a precise coordinate on a curved line in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections, bezier

I want to place two points on a trajectory, drawn as a curved line. I have manage to draw my curved line using *controls*. So i have this image :

[image]

with the following code :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (4,3) .. controls +(0,-2) and +(0.2,1) .. (5,0) ;

\draw (4,3) node[above]{$M$};
\draw (4,3) node{$\bullet$};
\draw (5,0) node[below]{$P$};
\draw (5,0) node{$\bullet$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However, I would like M and P to be only points of my trajectory, not its bound. Therefore, I would like to have them on the curve, but maybe M at y=2 and P and y=1. Is there a simple way to do that, that is, not adjusting mm by mm the position ?

Comment: You may use the `pos` option (section 17.8 "Placing Nodes on a Line or Curve Explicitly", p. 235, pgfmanual, v3.0.1a).

Comment: Thinking about it, as I can not yet accept my own answer, you comment is precious and solve my problem, but does not allow me to do what I wanted at the start, that is place the point on a given curve, given one coordinate.

Comment: To place a point precisely, you may use the `intersections` library (section 13.3.2 "Intersections of Arbitrary Paths", p. 138, pgfmanual, v3.0.1a).

Comment: To place a point precisely, read "[TikZ Nodes not exactly centered](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61343/tikz-nodes-not-exactly-centered)"...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are various solutions for my problem, all discovered with the help of [Paul Gaborit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/14500/paul-gaborit)'s comment.

I list three solutions, two of them do not need any additional library, one require the `intersections` library

## Without any additional library

The easiest solution consists on usgin in-built positioning options, that allow to mark a node with various combination of `midway`, `at start`, `at end`, `near start`, `very near start` and so on (I have not found a complete list...).

In this case, the code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (4,3) .. controls +(0,-2) and +(0.2,1) .. (5,0) 
    node[near end] {$\bullet$}
    node[near end, right] {$P$}
    node[very near start] {$\bullet$}
    node[very near start, right] {$M$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

yields me

[image]

These commands are in fact just particular values of a more general one, the `pos` option, that takes value in [0,1]. You can specify wherever you want your point on your line. I therefore get my desired result with this code :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (4,3) .. controls +(0,-2) and +(0.2,1) .. (5,0) 
    node[pos=0.8] {$\bullet$}
    node[pos=0.8, right] {$P$}
    node[pos=0.1] {$\bullet$}
    node[pos=0.1, right] {$M$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

## With the intersections library

So first, one needs to add `\usetikzlibrary{intersections}`

The above solutions enable to place the point everywhere, but do not allow to place it at a specific coordinate. If I want for instance the intersection of my curved line and the y=2.5 line, one needs the follonwing code :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[name path=y2] (4,2.5)--(5,2.5);
\path[name path=y1] (4,0.5)--(5,0.5);
\draw[name path=trajectory] (4,3) .. controls +(0,-2) and +(0.2,1) .. (5,0);

\fill [name intersections={of=y2 and trajectory}](intersection-1) circle (2pt) node[right] {$M$};
\fill [name intersections={of=y1 and trajectory}](intersection-1) circle (2pt) node[right] {$P$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Important points are : you need to name the objects you want to intersect, and to precise the number of your intersection (here only `(intersection-1)`  as there is just one).

The section **Intersections of Arbitrary Paths** in the Tikz-pgf manual gives more complex illustrations.

[image]